# issue in using model expression in ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I am using ng.deviceDetector for my browser version detection and thus use it in ng-if to skip one of the span tags but some how it is not working.
In my controller  `$scope.browserIdentity` is resulting 'ie9.0' but when I use it in ng-if to check it, the condition is not working correctly. Please find below code snippet for reference. When the browser identity is 'ie9.0' I want to skip my 'span' display (or remove from the DOM).

```
$scope.browserIdentity = $scope.deviceDetector.browser + $scope.deviceDetector.browser_version;

<span   ng-if="{{browserIdentity}} != 'ie9.0'" us-spinner="{radius:30, width:8, length: 16}" spinner-key="spinner-1"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-if="browserIdentity != 'ie9.0'"
```